# VS2022 Showing Lots of .TMP Files in Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, solution-explorer

My Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 Version 17.9.2 started creating and showing lots of .TMP files in Solution Explorer:

[image: .TMP Files]

These files are also visible in the Windows Explorer, are not deleted when I exit Visual Studio, and are included in search results creating lots of clutter:

[image]

Why is Visual Studio creating all these files and how do I prevent it from doing so or at least get it to stop displaying them in my Solution Explorer?

Comment: "Show All Files" option is not selected BTW.

Comment: Do you use F-Secure?

Comment: @Misaz No, I do not.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a ReSharper issue. ReSharper is creating all these files and as soon as it is disabled these files stop getting generated.

I created a post on ReSharper support forum so if you have the same issue you can track it [here](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/17375187047570-ReSharper-Creating-and-Showing-Lots-of-TMP-Files-in-Solution-Explorer-in-VS2022-Version-17-9-2)